# Cannot install Metrader 4 with Wine on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine

I'm trying to install metatrader 4 but every time the installation process hangs up while trying to download the necessary files from internet. Seems that **it cannot access at internet at all**... why?

Here is the photo of the installer searching for an "access point" to download files.

[image]

I tried all possible solutions/ideas:

- install the latest Wine version (1.9.x)
- install winetricks
- install the Microsoft Compatibility Layer
- install core fonts with *winetricks vcrun6* command
- install an older version of the metatrader4

Nothing works...
I'm crying...

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to so called "proxy issue". You can try installing windows http:

```
sudo apt install winbind
```

Winbind is a component of the Samba suite of programs that solves the unified logon problem. Winbind uses a UNIX implementation of Microsoft RPC calls.